# Why my download button is not doing anything? Firebase, react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm following the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?hl=es-419) for web to download the files related to a document in firestore. I practically pasted the code to achieve this, but when I click the element is not showing anything on console.

```
import { ref, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'

export const downloadMethod = (path) => {
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, path))
        .then(url => {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.onload = (event) => {
                const blob = xhr.response;
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.send();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw error
        })
}
```

Before this I was having cors error but I solved it using

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

I want the website to download the requested file when I hit the button.

Comment: `catch(error => {
            throw error
        })` - please stop doing this. At least log the error before throwing it again

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the reference to the storage

```
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
const storage = getStorage();
...
```

Comment: I already have the reference, when I hit the button there's no error on console or something

Answer (score 0):

Since the example in the documentation doesn't work, I looked for other methods in the documentation itself, and I managed to do exactly what I wanted by using `getBlob()`

This is my final function:

```
import { ref, getBlob } from 'firebase/storage'
import { storage } from '../firebase/firebase.config'

getBlob(ref(storage, 'files/MyFile.pdf'))
        .then((blob) => {
            const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            const a = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
                href,
                style: 'display:none',
                download: 'myFile.pdf' // This is where you set the name of the file you're about to download
            })
            a.click()

            URL.revokeObjectURL(href)
            a.remove()
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.error(error)
        })
```

If you feel there's something I can change, you can feel free to tell me